# .NET 7 MAUI not receiving http response

Tags: c#, maui, .net-7.0

I am playing around with .NET MAUI, and I got a problem. I call a rest API endpoint, and it is called, no errors (works 100% because I got response in Postman and on the SwaggerUI). But my mobile app client never receives a response. I probably miss something. Any idea is welcome.

```
    namespace Mobile.UI.Clients;

    public abstract class BaseClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private readonly MobileAppSettings settings;
    
        private string BaseURL
        {
            get
            {
                return DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ?
                                              this.settings.AndroidBaseURL : 
                                              this.settings.IosBaseURL;
            }
        }
    
        protected BaseClient(HttpClient httpClient, MobileAppSettings settings)
        {
            this.settings = settings;
    
            this.httpClient = BuildHttpClient(httpClient);
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a simple get request
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The return type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="route">The route part without the base url</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
        protected async Task<T> SendGetRequestAsync<T>(string route)
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = BuildUri(route);
    
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Faild to fetch data.");
                }
    
                var content = await SerializeResponse<T>(response.Content);
                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a simple get request
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The return type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="route">The route part without the base url</param>
        /// <param name="routParam">Rout parameter</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
        protected async Task<T> SendGetRequestAsync<T>(string route, object routParam)
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = BuildUri(route, routParam);
    
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Faild to fetch data.");
                }
    
                var content = await SerializeResponse<T>(response.Content);
                return content;
    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    
        private HttpClient BuildHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
    #if DEBUG
            var handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();
            httpClient = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler());
    #endif
    
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL);
    
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new("application/json"));
    
            return httpClient;
        }
    
        private Uri BuildUri(string route)
        { 
            return new Uri(Path.Combine(BaseURL, settings.ApiVersion, route));
        }
    
        private Uri BuildUri(string route, object routParam)
        {
            return new Uri(Path.Combine(BaseURL, settings.ApiVersion, route, $"{routParam}"));
        }
    
        private async Task<T> SerializeResponse<T>(HttpContent content)
        {
            var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream);
        }
    }
    
    public class PlayerClient : BaseClient, IPlayerClient
    {
        public PlayerClient(HttpClient httpClient, MobileAppSettings settings) : base(httpClient, settings)
        {}
    
        public async Task<List<PlayerModel>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var path = @"players/get-all";
            return await SendGetRequestAsync<List<PlayerModel>>(path);
        } 

}

    public class HttpsClientHandlerService : IHttpsClientHandlerService
    {
        public HttpMessageHandler GetPlatformMessageHandler()
        {
    #if ANDROID
                var handler = new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler();
                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    if (cert != null && cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                        return true;
                    return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
                };
                return handler;
    
    #elif IOS
                var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler
                {
                    TrustOverrideForUrl = IsHttpsLocalhost
                };
                return handler;
    
    #elif WINDOWS || MACCATALYST
                return null;
    #else
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Only Android, iOS, MacCatalyst, and Windows supported.");
    #endif
        }
    
    #if IOS    
        public bool IsHttpsLocalhost(NSUrlSessionHandler sender, string url, Security.SecTrust trust)
        {
            if (url.StartsWith("https://localhost"))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    #endif
    }
```

In the android message handler I captured an error (if it is an error):

> System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors | System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Comment: What value is `response` after it's done running `await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);`?

Comment: Don't use `localhost`.   Use the IP or FQDN of the server.   This has been discussed numerous times

Comment: Judging by IsHttpsLocalhost the url of the server you send request to is localhost, but it's unlikely your server runs on your phone.

Comment: @gunr2171 there is no response, and there is no exception

Comment: @Wasyster what do you mean "no response", the method returns null? The method returns response indicating failure? The code stops executing at that method? Exception is being thrown?

Comment: I mean I never receive a response, and that is the problem. The url is https://10.0.2.2:5001/api/v1/players/get-all, so I thing that is good, because It hits my endpoint.

Comment: @Evk that function in never got called in my local machine

Comment: @Wasyster ok, I will simplify it. When you debug this line of code: var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri); Is response "null"?

Comment: As as said it's not null, it's nothing because it fails to receive the response, and there is no error, nothing that should give me a guidance what goes wrong.

Comment: @Wasyster So, when you debug the code, you get exactly to this line:  var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri); and the execution does not continue from there?

Comment: Thats right, it just continues without any error, but not stops on the next line.

Comment: You should get a timeout error at the very least...

Comment: updated my question at the end

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it might help you get better errors.  In Visual Studio, debug right up until the line that doesn't do anything.  Then press CTRL + ALT + E to open the Exception Settings pane.  Click the box next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" until it's a Check (not a solid square), and then try to step over your line.  Hopefully your debugger will break and show you a more meaningful exception.  This doesn't _always_ work, but for me it works most of the time.

Comment: "it hits my endpoint" - are you sure?  Can you connect to the endpoint from the browser on the device/emulator?  Do the logs on your server show that it is receiving the request?

Comment: Are you [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) anywhere further up the call stack?

Comment: I found out that it needed more configuration for android for allow 10.0.0.2 address. It is needed to add an xml configuration file.

Comment: Can you please tell, what exactly you did to solve the problem?
I faced the same, but I try to connect not to localhost, but to published site. Running on Windows any made requests work fine, but on android - it is infinite request with no result